# A quick Galois Theory question

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, galois-theory, solution-verification

Let $\mathbb{F}_q$ be a finite field of order $q$ where $q$ is a prime power.

For any $d \in \mathbb{N},$ we have an inclusion $\mathbb{F}_{q^d} \subseteq \overline{\mathbb{F}}_q.$ Both $\text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q/\mathbb{F}_q)$ and $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{q^d}/\mathbb{F}_q)$ act on $\mathbb{F}_{q^d}.$

Question: is the orbit of any given $x \in \mathbb{F}_{q^d}$ the same under both groups?

Answer: Yes. Indeed, any $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{q^d}/\mathbb{F}_q)$ can be extended to some $\tau \in \text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q/\mathbb{F}_q)$ and conversely, if $\tau \in \text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_q/\mathbb{F}_q),$ then $\tau(x) \in \mathbb{F}_{q^d}$ and so, there exists some $\sigma \in \text{Gal}(\mathbb{F}_{q^d}/\mathbb{F}_q)$ such that $\sigma(x)=\tau(x).$ This proves the claim.

Is this correct?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Looks quite good to me. If this is the first time you do this kind of reasoning, it is probably worth your while to observe/state that you need the fact that $\Bbb{F}_{q^d}/\Bbb{F}_q$ is Galois. Otherwise it is not clear that $\tau(x)\in \Bbb{F}_{q^d}$. Because the relevant fields are finite and unique as subsets of an algebraic closure it is easy to forget that some steps do depend on this uniqueness.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your extra comments :)

Comment: Still in this case it might be easier to just list the conjugates. They are $x$, $x^q$, $x^{q^2}$, $\ldots$, $x^{q^{d-1}}$ in both cases.

Comment: In agreement with @JyrkiLahtonen’s comments, I think that your argument is perfect and applies to any Galois extension, not just the degree-$d$ extension of $\Bbb F_q$. But with the extra information that the smaller field is finite, you can simply, as he says, list the conjugates.